# Paused on exception Error: Cannot find module 'jquery.minicolors'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-2.7

Using

Ruby - 2.7.3
Rails - 6.1.3.2

Gem added -

```
gem 'jquery-minicolors-rails'
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("jquery")
require("jquery.minicolors")
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
*= require jquery.minicolors
```

View page code -

```
<%= f.input :light_background_color, as: :minicolors, input_html: {data: {
      minicolors: {position: :right}}} %>
```

but it throws the below error when we add code in the application.js file-

Paused on exception
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery.minicolors'

Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to use input type `color` from html5? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_color.asp

This gem looks like it's not updated for longer time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `require("...")` statements with

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.minicolors
```

in your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file

Comment: Module error is not thrown anymore but not showing to select color option